# How can I bring up in CSS the image of the avatar at the bottom of the posts of the Stories part in my case?

Tags: css

I would like to move the avatar located at the bottom of the Title of each post from the "STORIES" part circled in RED on the following screenshot:

[image]

**So that it goes up and positions itself at the bottom of the post card like this:**

[image]

But, the problem on my end is that when I try to do that, adding a `margin-top: -122px;` for example, hoping to succeed in bringing up the icon of the avatar in question, it does not work at all. Here is the code and CSS class of the avatar in question that I am trying to pull up to the bottom of the post card:

```
img.avatar.avatar-96.photo.td-animation-stack-type0-2 {
  margin-top: -122px;
}
```

**How then, manage to move this icon of the avatar in question to the bottom of each post so that it looks like the second screenshot above ???**

Thank you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add your avatar pic as a child in you `td-module-thumb` class

---

[image]

---

and give your avatar(child) it `position:absolute` then apply

```
.td-module-thumb{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  tranSform:translate(-50%);
}
```

---

```css
img{
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  
}

.td-module-thumb{
  background-color: bisque;
  width:250px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.td-module-thumb img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 75px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="td-module-thumb">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/100x100" alt="Avatar" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your different answers. But I don't find myself in any of the answers. Please I am looking for a better simple solution as I am using a wordpress theme and so the css code I should use should be just for customizing.

Comment: Add a snippet in answer. Basically you just need to cut your images HTML tag and paste inside `td-module-thumb` tags and apply customizing code above @GreZAKO

Comment: All right. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `td-module-meta-info` div into `td-module-thumb` div.

Comment: Why? Can you explain why you expect this to solve the problem? An [edit] with clarification would be useful here.